# My notepad txt file turned into weird characters

Tags: windows, notepad++, text-editors, notepad, decoding

Some years ago I wrote some notes in a .txt file (plain text) on Notepad and when I opened it recently it appeared with [these weird characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JleDz.png). I don't know at what point it turned out like that, but it could have been in-between a transition from a Windows 7 -> External Drive -> Windows 10 (current).

Another .txt files that were in the same folder as this one got like that, although the majority hadn't changed. This makes me suspect of either a conversion error between Microsoft OS or the files got corrupted.

Also, when I opened with Notepad++, this same file was written [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7mI7.png) . When I copied it to google translate textbox, the characters with black background turned into [some kind of coded matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tTzc.png), so maybe it can give some kind of clue.

I already tried to decode through many ways without being successful. Maybe someone has any idea if this is a matter that can be solved through decoding to Plain Text (ASCII), or if the files are corrupted and there is no way back.

Thanks.

Comment: What language were the files written in?

Comment: Please post one (small) file. Can it be that you wrote in Unicode without a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Some years ago I wrote some notes in a .txt file (plain text) on Notepad and when I opened it recently it appeared with these weird characters. I don't know at what point it turned out like that, but it could have been in-between a transition from a Windows 7 -> External Drive -> Windows 10 (current).
>
> Another .txt files that were in the same folder as this one got like that, although the majority hadn't changed. This makes me suspect of either a conversion error between Microsoft OS or the files got corrupted.

The files got corrupted. It might be a hardware problem or an OS problem, although it's much more likely that they got corrupted when copying from/to the external drive (e.g. via bad USB connection or the drive was damaged) and not during an OS upgrade.

> when I opened with Notepad++, this same file was written like this . When I copied it to google translate textbox, the characters with black background turned into some kind of coded matrix, so maybe it can give some kind of clue.

These are ["control characters"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes) – they're meant to be interpreted by programs and not shown on screen, and normally they wouldn't occur in a text file at all (except for CR/LF/TAB of course). Therefore they don't have a standard visual representation, and different programs have different ways of displaying them if they *do* occur:

- Notepad++ (well, its Scintilla core) shows each character's name from the ASCII standard, e.g. byte 0x03 is "EOT" (End-of-Transmission) and 0x18 is "CAN" (Cancel). Some of these names date back to the telegraph era.
- Your browser uses the same method to show all unprintable characters – the 'matrix' is just a four-digit number indicating that character's Unicode codepoint. (In this case they're the U+0018 aka CAN, U+0003 aka EOT, and so on.)

  You can see the same box-with-digits for any character that the OS doesn't have in its fonts, e.g. it will show up for newly released emojis that the OS/browser doesn't yet support.

> I already tried to decode through many ways without being successful. Maybe someone has any idea if this is a matter that can be solved through decoding to Plain Text (ASCII), or if the files are corrupted and there is no way back.

In Notepad++, the file looks *kind of* like it's half-UTF-8 and half-garbage (the accented-'A's tend to show up when an UTF-8 file is misinterpreted as Windows-1252).

However, in this case it's probably just a coincidence and there's likely nothing decodable in this file anymore.

Comment: I imagine it may be a result of malware's actions too.

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late for the OP, but I thought someone like me might face the same problem and come here to what seems to be a dead end. But I found a solution! I simply uploaded the file to Google Drive and opened using Google Docs... and it was fine! Then I resaved the data as a Word file, and hopefully that's that. I'm no expert but it would seem to me Notepad or Windows has undergone *some* change in the past couple of years since I created the original txt file. Hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me when I transitioned from Windows 7 to 10. Prior to that I have never had a problem, & I've used dozens of text files for 20 years, all OK.
This has been with Windows 10 since its release & it's still there. My advice is to keep your text files with multiple serial backups, & keep them below about 300K size. You'll need the backups to repair the garbled text (copy & paste), because the problem will arise & trash part of your file if you use Windows 10. That's the answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).